# Java JPA OneToMany relation and query

Tags: java, jpa

maybe duplicate question but I couldn't fina a solution for my case which I think is pretty simple.

I have two tables like so :

[image]

And those are the related DTO Object :

First table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DA10003_REF_SIGNALEMENT")
public class RefSignalement {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CD_SIGNALEMENT")
    public String codeSignalement;

    @Column(name = "LIBELLE")
    public String libelle;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORIE")
    public String categorie;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_SIGNALEMENT")
    public List<RefMessage> refMessages;
}
```

Second table :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DA10004_REF_MESSAGE")
public class RefMessage {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CD_SIGNALEMENT")
    public String codeSignalement;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DESTINATAIRE")
    public String destinataires;

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
    public String message;
}
```

And the following query to get all the `RefSignelement` with the associated message :

```
List<RefSignalement> listRefSignalement = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM RefSignalement p, RefMessage m", RefSignalement.class).getResultList();
```

Unfortunately it's returning an empty list, I have tried to change it with `join fetch` but nothing change.

Thank for the help

Comment: What list is empty exactly and if it is the list of RefSignalement  instances, how are you checking that there are any in the database? Its a common mistake to point tests at the wrong test database that might be empty. This query is wrong too, so that if you had results, you would get duplicate RefSignalement for each RefMessage instance in the database - you added RefMessage m into the from clause but did nothing to relate it to the RefSignalement p.

Comment: @Chris I made some changes in the objects entity and code and now it's working but as you mentioned I'm getting duplicate RefSignalement, and so I tried with this query `SELECT s FROM RefSignalement s JOIN FETCH s.refMessages` and it's the same result getting multiple object for each instance and more over if a RefSignalement doesn't have a related data in RefMessage it doesn't show up at all

Comment: I've added DISTINCT to the query which fixed the problem some how, but when I add data in my db the results is not changing I have really weird behavior

Comment: DISTINCT Doesn't make sense to me, but if it works, great, but should cause less results not more. You should use  LEFT OUTER JOIN if you are joining something and want to include nulls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in JPQL you have to think in Objects, not relations. You want to fetch all 'RefSignalement' and eagerly fetch their 'refMessages' properties:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s FROM RefSignalement s JOIN FETCH s.refMessages
```

Here the "distinct" is only needed by JPA when assembling your resulting entities, but add unnecessary overhead to the SQL Query. If you have a Hibernate version >= 5.2.2 (I think), then there is a query hint you can use to avoid that:

```
List<RefSignalement> sigs = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select distinct s " +
    "from RefSignalement s " +
    "left join fetch s.refMessages ")
.setHint("hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough", false)
.getResultList();
```

Read more about it [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpql-distinct-jpa-hibernate/).

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately I'm still getting an empty list

Comment: @ImadElHitti thank's, I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

a couple of things,  `RefMessage` class is using composite primary key so i guess you need to use `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId` annotation. here I'm providing using 
`@IdClass`

```
public class RefId implements Serializable {

private String codeSignalement;

private String destinataires;

// default constructor


public RefId() {
}

public RefId(String codeSignalement, String destinataires) {
    this.codeSignalement = codeSignalement;
    this.destinataires = destinataires;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    RefId refId = (RefId) o;
    return Objects.equals(codeSignalement, refId.codeSignalement) &&
            Objects.equals(destinataires, refId.destinataires);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(codeSignalement, destinataires);
}
}
```

then you need to use  like follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DA10004_REF_MESSAGE")
@IdClass(RefId.class)
public class RefMessage   {

@Id
@Column(name = "CD_SIGNALEMENT")
public String codeSignalement;

@Id
@Column(name = "DESTINATAIRE")
public String destinataires;

@Column(name = "MESSAGE")
public String message;
}
```

define your repository as follows:

```
public interface RefSignalementRepo  extends 
JpaRepository<RefSignalement, String> {
}
```

`RefSignalement` class defination as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DA10003_REF_SIGNALEMENT")
public class RefSignalement {

@Id
@Column(name = "CD_SIGNALEMENT")
public String codeSignalement;

@Column(name = "LIBELLE")
public String libelle;

@Column(name = "CATEGORIE")
public String categorie;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "CD_SIGNALEMENT")
public List<RefMessage> refMessages;
}
```

very example app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
   SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);


    RefSignalementRepo repo = context.getBean(RefSignalementRepo.class);

    RefSignalement obj = new RefSignalement();
    obj.codeSignalement = "1";

    obj = repo.save(obj);

    obj.refMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    RefMessage message = new RefMessage();
    message.codeSignalement = "1";
    message.destinataires = "2";
    message.message = "custom message";

    obj.refMessages.add(message);

    obj = repo.save(obj);

    List<RefSignalement> objs = repo.findAll();

    System.out.println(objs.get(0).refMessages.size());


    EntityManager em = context.getBean(EntityManager.class);

    List<RefSignalement> listRefSignalement = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM RefSignalement p, RefMessage m", RefSignalement.class).getResultList();


    System.out.println(listRefSignalement.get(0).refMessages.size());

}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I made the changes for the composite key indeed it's the way I should go. Unfortunately it didn't change anything and I'm still getting an empty list I can't understand why

Comment: @ImadElHitti I have updated the code. can you follow the example code and try now plz

Comment: Hello I tried the solution, it seems working but not completely as I'm getting twice the result, If I have one RefSignalement and two RefMessage associated, Im getting two same object RefSignalement in my array list